# Chemical equilibrium graph

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

[image]
How can we determine which reaction belongs to which graph.
I mean in the above pic . We can observe two graphs and 2 equations. But there is no link between the two . Both the reactions proceed till completion . So both graphs must be a straight line . But that’s not the answer . I would appreciate if you could help me in finding the reason to the above problem Thank you for your help.

Source: problems in physical chemistry by narendra Awasthi

Comment: This is a graph without time on the x-axis. It describes how product and reactant concentrations are correlated. The axes are mislabeled, they should say amount (or maybe concentration) of reactant and product. Also, b) does not have a correct answer. Could you edit your question to include where you found the flawed execise?

Comment: Here is a textbook section with some context for the reactant vs product type of graph: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_General_Chemistry%3A_Principles_Patterns_and_Applications_(Averill)/15%3A_Chemical_Equilibrium/15.04%3A_Non-equilibrium_Conditions

Comment: @KarstenTheis I found it in a book used to prepare for IITJEE

Comment: @KarstenTheis but how did you figure out that 2 nd one is wrong and the first is right . I didn’t get the logic

Comment: @Integer Consider a generic reaction A+B->C, which has equilibrium constant K=[C]/[A][B]. What would a graph of product [C] vs. reactant [A] look like, holding concentration of B constant? Manipulate the law of mass action (equilibrium expression) and obtain [C]=(K[B])*[A] which is a linear equation of the form y=mx. Apply this logic to your examples, keeping in mind that only aqueous and gas phases are included in the equilibrium constant. For the iodine reaction (solvation), K=[I2(aq)], so there is not a relationship between the product and reactant to plot.

Comment: This actually is not a bad question IMO. If @Integer can clean this up and garner reopen votes, it would be a welcome addition I think.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt I would argue that the question from the OP is good and the exercise from the photo needs work.

Comment: According @electronpusher comment reaction(A) belongs to graph (Q).

Comment: I think that the graph is not accurate as the graph indicates that the concentration of the reactant is zero

Comment: @AdnanAL-Amleh I agree rxn A corresponds to graph Q. I'm not sure what your second comment means. Both graphs have a point where the reactant concentration is zero, and this implies that the product concentration will also be zero. This should be understandable, we are talking about equilibrium not conversion. Assuming not all reactant gets used up (conversion less than 100%), at equilibrium there must be at least some reactant in order for there to be any product.

Comment: @electronpusher"Both graphs have a point where the reactant concentration is zero, and this implies that the product concentration will also be zero" what about the K value ?